# getResources().getIdentifier problem

Tags: android

In one activity, there are 1 text view and 1 image view. I have to display number of data for different images. I have stored the data in string-array in strings.xml. My code is working fine for them. Problem is with images. I have stored images in R.raw folder. How can I get the images in image view so that for every data corresponding images can be displayed.

In the listactivity(where the data are displayed in a listview i have added async task and in doinbackground i am loading values from these arrays ). I am stuck in images. How to do that? pls help...

started like  this,

```
int image[]= {getResources().getIdentifier("aa", "raw", getPackageName()),

    getResources().getIdentifier("bb", "raw", getPackageName()),
    getResources().getIdentifier("cc", "raw", getPackageName()),};
```

Pls reply..
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why are the images in Raw? Put them into /drawble-hdpi or /drawable-mdpi...whatever and then set the image by myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage) and then associate it with your data however you want...

Answer (score 0):

For resources in your `raw` folder, you should be able to use [Bitmap.decodeResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) to obtain an image you can pass to the ImageView.

Comment: I have to display images corresponding to the data. How can I do that? any example will be great..I am a beginner in java n android...